# Why can we split product averages of stochastic processes? $\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\dots x(t_N) \rangle = \langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle \dots$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For white Gaussian or dichotomous stochastic processes it is often stated that averages can be split into a sum of all possible products of two point correlation functions:
$$ \langle \prod_n x(t_{n})\rangle = \sum_{(s_1,s_2,\dots)}\langle x(t_{s_1})x(t_{s_2})\rangle \langle x(t_{s_3})x(t_{s_4}) \rangle \dots. $$
Why is this so, and for what reason is this identity limited to only Gaussian and dichotomous noises? It has been tough for me to find a clear answer on this from the books I have access to.

Comment: In the Gaussian case you are missing a sum over all possible ways of pairing of the gaussian R.V.s (this result is known as Wick's theorem or sometimes as Isserlis' theorem; the Wikipedia page is called the latter because there are too many different results called Wick's theorem). The result does have a generalisation to the non-Gaussian setting; the so-called moments-cumulants expansion.

Comment: Thanks @Rhys - fixed that.